# Image file cannot be resolved

Tags: typo3, phpstorm, fluid

The file of an image I used in an productbox cannot be resolved anymore.

I used this tag `f:uri.image(src:bild.url,crop:bild.crop)}` and PhpStorm throws me this error from now on, I did not recognize this message when I used it in other projects, but it`s also happening there.

Seems to be a current problem maybe with some Viewhelper Updates or the TYPO3 Version, I used TYPO3 v8.7.18 and v.8.7.4.

Anyone got a similar issue?

Comment: PhpStorm is an IDE for the PHP programming language but you appear to be using a different technology. Can you please edit the question and clarify that?

Comment: please attach a screenshot of a code or a code piece. Too little context here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default PhpStorm does not know about `fluid`. So PhpStorm probably tries to validate the fluid against HTML syntax which will fail, as there are tags not included in HTML. Also if you use fluid-variables where in HTML strings are used PhpStorm will fail.